# Ruby on Rails connection SQL Oracle problems

Tags: sql, ruby, oracle, ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu

I'm trying to setup SQL Oracle and use active records to migrate db with ruby on rails.
I installed sqldeveloper and created a new connection. Here the first error:

**I/O error: The Network Adapeter could not establish the connection**

Then I installed instantclient basic, sdk, sqlplus and then two gems:

`gem 'ruby-oci8'`

`gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter'`

but I got this error:

**LoadError: Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile.**

this is my database.yml:

```
# SQLite version 3.x

#   gem install sqlite3

#

#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile

#   gem 'sqlite3'

#

development: 

adapter: oracle 

database: development 

username: nick 

password: 


# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and 

# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake". 

# Do not set this db to the same as development or production. 

test: 

adapter: oracle 

database: test 

username: nick 

password: 


production: 

adapter: oracle 

database: production  

username: nick 

password:
```

I wasn't able to find a solution, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Update `adapter` entries as follows:

`adapter: oracle`

to

`adapter: oracle_enhanced`

Comment: This is the new log:

Warning: NLS_LANG is not set. fallback to US7ASCII.
rake aborted!
OCIError: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
oci8.c:654:in oci8lib_210.so

Comment: I think you need to edit `database` value as you connect sqlplus user/password@database.

Also you can refer this readme. https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/blob/master/README.md

Comment: The real problem is the error **I/O error: The Network Adapeter could not establish the connectio**. I can't find a solution...